# how to close activated sessions and force user to re-enter his credentials in identity server 4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core, identityserver4

One user can log in through multiple systems with various IP addresses, so is there any way to deactivate one of his sessions? (or all other sessions except the current logged in one) if yes, how?
The thing I want to do is exactly like Telegram which you are able to close any of your activated sessions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is not new here, it appears a couple times a month in different interpretations, and the answer is still: there is no such feature out of the box, but there are a couple approaches:

The first one is to use Reference Token (instead of jwt by default), then look through the persisted grants database and logout all the sessions for the target userId.

The other approach is to implement your custom session store based on a database (instead of the cookie based by default). Then you again have access to all the clients logged in with the given user id. [Here](https://github.com/dfrunet/IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI/blob/master/Extensions/ExtendedUserSession.cs) is my old (but still valid) example of a hybrid (cookie + `IDistributedCache` such as REDIS) extension for the `DefaultUserSession`. Here you have to be careful with access token lifetime (make it reasonably short), as a jwt once issued can not be invalidated before its normal expiration.