# How can I get a list of logged in users with IdenityServer4?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-core-webapi, identityserver4

I've an AspnetCore + Angular setup where the authentication part is handled by IdentityServer4. One of the requirements now is to get a list of all users who are currently logged in. Any ideas/suggestions how to proceed on this?

> PS: Just in case it's needed, I'm using implicit flow .

Comment: By default the sessions are cookie based without any central store. You can look into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57830342/how-to-close-activated-sessions-and-force-user-to-re-enter-his-credentials-in-id/) my recent answer for possible options.

Answer (score 1):

Auth is persisted via a cookie, which lives client-side. The server doesn't know who all is logged in. It only know in the context of a particular request (where the client sends the auth cookie back) whether that particular client is authenticated or not.

If you *really* need this, you'll need to manually track it yourself somehow, like adding a record to a table for each login. However, this can get gnarly fast. You'll need to also manage sign outs and expirations, to keep your custom data fresh.

Answer (score 1):

A generic answer could be: *ASP.NET CORE keeps each user session in a cookie, separately located at each user's browser on each device. Once you need, you have to centralize that system yourself*. Howerwer, since the question regards `Identityserver`, we can look into what is already done in that area by the IdentityServer authors. And they have provided at least two extensibility points.

The first one is to employ [Reference Token](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/reference_tokens.html) (instead of the jwt by default), then look through the persisted grants database, fetch all the sessions grouped by userId. Not a standard way for OpenIdConnect, but it exists.

The other approach is to implement your *custom session store* based on a database (instead of the cookie based by default). That provides you access to all the clients logged in with the given user id. [Here](https://github.com/dfrunet/IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI/blob/master/Extensions/ExtendedUserSession.cs) is my old (but still valid) example of a hybrid (cookie + `IDistributedCache` such as REDIS) extension for the `DefaultUserSession`. Usually after the requirement to list all the user sessions, appears the other one: to create a *kill the session* button next to each row. Here you have to be careful with access token lifetime (make it reasonably short), as a jwt once issued can not be invalidated before its normal expiration.

Answer (score 0):

There is provision in the default cookie provider in ASP.Net Core to use a DB or distributed cache to store cookie payloads. Check out the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.ITicketStore` interface and the `CookieAuthenticationOptions.SessionStore` property.

We created our own implementation that stores auth cookies in the PersistedGrants table along with IDS4 stuff. It works well, keeps cookies small and facilitates a "sign out on all devices" option also. If you align the expiry of the entry with the cookie authentication properties then the housekeeping is done for you.